Finding time to cover distance for a moving object with a "custom" velocity function.
I'm working on a game where I have a moving object and I have to figure out how long it takes for it to cover a given distance.
Now, the physics engine that controls its movement runs at 60 frames per second, and on each frame it multiplies the velocity of the object by a drag coefficient.
I've come up with this function that models the way the velocity of the object changes:
$$ v(t) = {v_0} * d^{FPS * t} $$
Where $ {v_0} $ is the initial velocity, $ d $ is the drag coefficient and $ FPS $ is the amount of frames per second.
Now, my next idea was that by integrating this function, I'd be able to find the space covered in a given amount of time.
$$ \int_0^t {v_0} * d^{FPS * t} dt $$
which resulted in:
$$ \frac{{v_0}(d^{FPS * t} - 1)}{FPS * ln(d)} = s $$
where $ s $ is the space covered.
Now, by re-arranging things a bit, I'd get:
$$ t = \frac{ln[\frac{s * FPS * ln(d)}{{v_0}} + 1]}{FPS * ln(d)} $$
But the issue I have here is that if $ d = 1 $, then I get 0 in the denominator, which I think means that all my calculations are faulty. Even if $ d $ is less than one, I end up getting a negative parameter for the logarithm in the numerator.
I'm not sure why, though, and I'd greatly appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Your calculations are all correct. The solution of the integral just has a different form for the special case $d=1$. Hint: $\lim_{d\rightarrow 1}\frac{d^a - 1}{\ln d} = a$.
